# Get last item in a nested field ElasticSearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I use ElasticSearch to store data. I want to get the last item in a nested field. More specifically, the last element of the message array. Data structure  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZBpv.png)

Comment: Please tell us what all you have tried till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scripted_fields` in search query to find last element of array.

For example, the sample data look like this:

```
POST room/_doc
{
  "message": [
    {"date": "2019-12-11T11:21:29.060Z", "name":"", "id":"SYSTEM_MESSAGE"},
    {"date": "2019-12-11T11:21:41.525Z", "name":"n910827m", "id":"SYSTEM_MESSAGE"}
  ],
  "name": "hello",
  "superuser": "9hxj0BNxs4AppB7kAAAD"
}
```

And, if you want to find the last element of `message` field, search query is look like this:

```
POST room/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "message": {
      "script": {
        "source": 
        """
        def messages = params['_source']['message'];
        return messages[messages.length - 1];
        """, 
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]